# Why is thread.sleep used in this method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm following a tutorial on https://proghammer.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/chess07-new-game-flow-handling/

I don't understand the use of Thread.sleep in the waitForMove() method
I've changed the time to 0 and it still works fine, but if I remove it
it feels like the game is freezing in a certain state, why is it needed ?

Thank you

```
public class ChessGame implements Runnable{

       //..

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.startGame();
    }

    /**
     * start main game flow
     */
    public void startGame(){
        // check if all players are ready
        System.out.println(&quot;ChessGame: waiting for players&quot;);
        while (this.blackPlayerHandler == null || this.whitePlayerHandler == null){
            // players are still missing
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        // set start player
        this.activePlayerHandler = this.whitePlayerHandler;

        // start game flow
        System.out.println(&quot;ChessGame: starting game flow&quot;);
        while(!isGameEndConditionReached()){
            waitForMove();
            swapActivePlayer();
        }

        System.out.println(&quot;ChessGame: game ended&quot;);
    }

    /**
     * wait for a valid player move and execute it
     */
    private void waitForMove() {
        Move move = null;
        // wait for a valid move
        do{
            move = this.activePlayerHandler.getMove();
            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }while(move == null || !this.moveValidator.isMoveValid(move,false));

        //execute move
        boolean success = this.movePiece(move);
        if(success){
            this.blackPlayerHandler.moveSuccessfullyExecuted(move);
            this.whitePlayerHandler.moveSuccessfullyExecuted(move);
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException(&quot;move was valid, but failed to execute it&quot;);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a delaying tact, basically it makes the `startGame` method wait 1 second between checks for both players.  You could use a `CountDownLatch` or `Semaphore` instead, which might be more efficient.  Remember, a "free wheeling" loop is very inefficient!

Comment: Why does it make the startGame method wait ? startGame is called once isn't it ?

Comment: My advice:  close that Wordpress page and never look at it again.  The author does not know what he’s doing.  A spin-loop monitoring non-volatile objects with no thread synchronization might run *forever.*  The Java Language Specification even has [an example describing that exact scenario](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) with an explanation of why it’s wrong.

Comment: @Arietyie The loop is "attempting" to ensure that both players have been set before proceeding.  Personally, it should not be called UNTIL both players have been set - if one or both players are not defined at this point, it should trigger a runtime exception as the state has not been properly initialised.  But I also agree with VGR, it's a bad example

Comment: What would a good example look like ? This is the first time i'm making a game, I don't know much about loop. Do you have any resources where I can learn from ?